# Unparse a command line from a dict in Python

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

Python's `argparse` library allows parsing command line arguments into a [`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) which can then be turned into a dict using `vars()`. However, can I use an `ArgumentParser` in reverse, to output a command line string from a dict, and if so, how?

Comment: You almost certainly can not, because it's not guaranteed to be a one-to one mapping to begin with. For example, what if you have multiple options that append to the same destination variable?

Comment: If you have a specific simplified usecase, you can always write your own code to do it.

Comment: `argparse` does not have any such code.  For simpler cases it wouldn't be hard to write a string from a dictionary that would work as a command line.

Comment: `' '.join([f'--{key}={val}' for key, val in adict.items()])`